# Image memory in gtk+

Tags: image, gtk, cairo

I'm new in the field of gtk+. My question is that is there a way to render images very fast in gtk??? I mean is there a way to directly alter the image data in frame buffer or video ram or something like that? Do pixbufs do the same thing?? I need to apply this for a scrolling example. Is cairo good for fast rendering of images?

Answer (score 0):

GTK is a high-level toolkit, which means that you can't do that sort of low-level manipulation. However, GTK has plenty of facilities for fast scrolling built in. You can also render images to Cairo surfaces in memory. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Thnx for you reply...I am actually displaying an image(which is scrolling) in cairo. The image data is in memory. So I am simply reading a few bytes in a pixbuf and then using gdk-cairo-set-source-pixbuf() to set the cairo surface as the data contained in pixbuf. The pixbuf will be loaded with new values as and when new data is available.The surface on which cairo draws is a gtk drawing area. My requirement is that scrolling should be smooth and fast. But I'm unable to do so. Is there any func call that is analogous to XCopyArea or XPutImage in gtk+?